# What are ways processing long running queries with Node?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need to pull a large amount of data from another server and then save to my database ( mongodb). What is the best way to handle processing long running queries. The another consider is that there will be a good number of users of the app. They will intiate the similar requests to pull the data from the remote server and save it to our server.

I have found a various options like queue-worker, cluster, etc . I am new to NodeJs so I am a bit confused.  Which one will be the best or is there any other solution I might consider.

Comment: Sounds like you need some kind of background worker system. As for which one, that's hugely subjective, so just see what's out there and give some a try. I've built several systems with Node leaning on [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com) but there are plenty of other options worth exploring.

Comment: yes, there is not the one best solution. When importing lots of data from an other system you might want to learn about streams, generator functions very new and hot today `for await` loops. How to handle many of such hobs is a different question, of organizing those tasks. as already said, a pub/sub messaging service like RabbitMQ is a good option. I would say: try to solve one problem after the other.